# What is the link between the classical and quantum definition of the symmetry number?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, energy, symmetry, dipole

From what I understand, the symmetry number for a molecule can be defined in 2 ways:

**1.** The quantum mechanical symmetry number corrects for overcounting the number of possible rotational states of a rotating molecule. Here's a [source](http://mit.uvt.rnu.tn/courses/chemistry/5-62-physical-chemistry-ii-spring-2008/lecture-notes/13_562ln08.pdf) using this method.

**2.** The classical symmetry number corrects for including physical orientations of that molecule that appear the same because of its symmetrical physical structure. Here's a [source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XRIcYt7CR8oX6bsEg3NHYv4fiO2ug1AP/view?usp=sharing) using this method (a PDF file)

[This source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-62-physical-chemistry-ii-spring-2008/lecture-notes/12_562ln08.pdf) claims at the end of page 3, that the classical view is roughly based on the quantum view. I have a very hard time to grasp that.

How does the physical structure of a molecule have anything to do with nuclear spins being integer or half-integers, whether the total wavefunction needs to be symmetrical or antisymmetrical, and thus determining which rotational quantum states are allowed for a molecule?

Comment: Without looking at the actual links, the statement that the "classical view is based on the  quantum view" is non-sensical. The classical view for any system is derived from immediate observables. That's why it's classical. The quantum view requires an understanding of quantum mechanics, historically arriving much later. How could the earlier view be based on the latter view?

Comment: on page 3, $\sigma$ is constant, nothing to do with quantum or classical, but is 2 for homonuclear molecules because it is not possible to tell left from right and so extra counting is accounted for.

Comment: @Zhe That is what I am trying to understand. If you look at page 3 of [this source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-62-physical-chemistry-ii-spring-2008/lecture-notes/12_562ln08.pdf), it says the following: **The symmetry number is rigorously based on the nuclear spins**. Here, the symmetry number corrects for the number of physical orientations of a molecule that are indistinguishable. How is this based on nuclear spins?

Comment: @porphyrin Please also see this end of page 6 of this [source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-62-physical-chemistry-ii-spring-2008/lecture-notes/13_562ln08.pdf). Initially on page 3, it derived the symmetry number $\sigma$ based on nuclear spins and wavefunction symmetry to correct for the number of allowed quantum states with the factor $\frac{1}{\sigma}$ for the partition function. But on page 6 it says **$\frac{1}{\sigma}$ is of classical mechanical origin, but must come out of QM**

Comment: That appears to be extending classical statistical mechanics so that it's consistent with quantum mechanics.

Comment: in a more accurate derivation p 6 the factor of 2 appears naturally, (plus other terms) earlier on $\sigma$ is obtained classically by symmetry and as is classical should only apply at high temp. By that statement they mean that if  classical sigma is correct, then a full  QM derivation should produce same result. It is a clear derivation .

Comment: @porphyrin In that case, it makes me question how one deduced that structural symmetry has something to do with correcting for the number of allowed quantum states.  Is there a way to explain this?

Comment: this is shown in the source you quote towards the end of the derivations.

Comment: @porphyrin What I'm saying is, how does a correction based on the physical structure of a molecule determine which quantum states are allowed or not allowed semantically? I can see no link how the symmetry number is semantically connected to the total wavefunction being symmetrical/anti-symmetrical.